# Graphviz Python - access and modify nodes in grpah

Tags: python, visualization, graphviz

I was able to write code which is autogenerating graph based on XAML file which is working fine. However I would like to be able to combine few graph as clusters in one big graph.
Questions:

1. Which property in graph/ cluster object is storing nodes added by method:

   Cluster.node(x,y)
   So where is it in Cluster object?
2. Is it possible to replace nodes?
3. Does graphviz Python library provide possibility to build interactive graphs?
   If no, does anyone of you know what I can use instead of it?

That what I have in form of array of clusters
And I want to combine them like on picture next to it
[image]